# Calculating the two-point correlation of pixel intensity in an image

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, image-processing, correlation

I'm dealing with a monochromatic image represented by a matrix of pixel intensities, something like this:

```
myImage = {{1, 4, 6}, {0, 3, 1}, {9, 1, 1}}
```

I wish to calculate the following quantity, called the two-point correlation:

$$C(\Delta x) = \langle I(x)I(x+\Delta x) \rangle$$

In the formula, the $I(x)$ denotes the pixel intensity value at the x-coordinate or the column index of some pixel and $I(x+ \Delta x)$ is the same at a different x-coordinate or column index, separated by distance $\Delta x$. The outer angle brackets denote averaging over all pairs of pixels in the image.

How do I go about doing this? I figured I must start with a list of all possible pairs of pixels in the image, so I need to do `Permutations[myImage]`. In the end, I need a list of tuples, each tuple being `{del x, C(del x)}` for a certain `del x`. How do I proceed in the cleanest way from here?

Comment: What are you going to do at the edges, such as when $x+\Delta x$ is greater than 3?

Comment: @Ghoster Hmm, maybe I don’t understand you correctly, but if you look at pairs of pixels, their relative x-distance cannot be more than 3, considering my example. And what I am interested in is a quantity that is a function of this relative distance.

Comment: ImageCorrelate with a translation kernel exists.  The sum over all pixels is done by Total[ImageData[ image, 2]], Another route is ListCorrelate[ ImageData[ image ]].